# Is it possible to save multiple array of objects into one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have multiple array of objects and I want to **data1** to be stored to **allData**. Eventually **data2 and data 3** will be appended to **allData** as well. I know this works for arrays. But does this works for an array of objects?

```
var allData;

var data1 = [
  {movie: 'Avengers Infinity War', rating: 4.8},
  {movie: 'Avengers End Game', rating: 4.5},
  {movie: 'Avengers End Age of Ultron', rating: 4.5}
]

var data2 = [
  {movie: 'Iron Man', rating: 4.3},
  {movie: 'Captain America: The First Avernger', rating: 4.7}
]

var data3 = [
  {movie: 'Thor', rating: 4.7},
]

allData = data1;
allData = allData.concat(data2);
allData = allData.concat(data3);
console.log(allData);
```

**EDIT:**
I have updated my code to my question. My apologies.

Comment: How is an array of objects any different from a simpler array? Have you tried anything?

Comment: An array of objects is still an array.

Comment: ah its ok. i think i got it?

Comment: So there is no question here

Answer (score 3):

```
allData = [...data1, ...data2, ...data3]
```

or

```
allData = data1.concat(data2).concat(data3)
```

Comment: ah this is just what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Yes It works.

```
allData = [...data1,...data2,...data3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add arrays to allData and use `flat` method.

```js
var allData;

var data1 = [
  { movie: "Avengers Infinity War", rating: 4.8 },
  { movie: "Avengers End Game", rating: 4.5 },
  { movie: "Avengers End Age of Ultron", rating: 4.5 }
];

var data2 = [
  { movie: "Iron Man", rating: 4.3 },
  { movie: "Captain America: The First Avernger", rating: 4.7 }
];

var data3 = [{ movie: "Thor", rating: 4.7 }];

allData = [data1, data2, data3].flat();

console.log(allData);
```